# Sequelize Transaction inside forEach loop

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use transaction inside `forEach` loop using async/await syntax of Node 7.0+

When I try to print committed transaction response in console, I'm able to see the values but those same values are not committed in to DB.

Below is the code :

```js
documentInfo.forEach(async (doc) => { // array of documentInfo
    var frontImgName = await module.exports.uploadImage(docFiles, doc.front, req, res )
    var backImgName = await module.exports.uploadImage(docFiles, doc.back, req, res )

    var checkKycDoc = await KYCDocument.findOne({
        where: {
            kyc_id: checkUserKyc.dataValues.kyc_id,
            user_id: checkUserKyc.dataValues.user_id
        }
    })

    if (checkKycDoc) { //update
        var updateDocument = await KYCDocument.update({
            document_name: doc.document_name,
            front_image: frontImgName,
            back_image: backImgName
        }, {
            where: {
                kyc_id: checkUserKyc.dataValues.kyc_id,
                user_id: checkUserKyc.dataValues.user_id
            },
        }, {transaction})

        log('updateDocument', updateDocument.dataValues)

    } else { // insert
        var newKycDocument = await new KYCDocument({
            kyc_id: checkUserKyc.dataValues.kyc_id,
            user_id: checkUserKyc.dataValues.user_id,
            document_name: doc.document_name,
            front_image: frontImgName,
            back_image: backImgName,
            status: true
        }, {transaction})

        log('newKycDocument', newKycDocument.dataValues)
    }
    if (rowCount === documentInfo.length) {
        await transaction.commit() // transaction is printed on this line
        log('KYC has been uploaded successfully')
        helpers.createResponse(res, constants.SUCCESS,
            messages.KYC_UPLOAD_SUCCESS,
            {'error': messages.KYC_UPLOAD_SUCCESS}
        )
    } else {
        rowCount++
    }

})
```

Comment: I presume the transaction is actually started "outside" the `.forEach()`. In all honesty it would really make more sense to commit "after" all iterations are done, rather than attempting a commit on each iteration ( I know it's an `if` condition, but that's not the point ). As such, a `for of` loop makes a lot more sense here at least from an aesthetic point of view. Also you probably should be sticking to the ["managed" transactions](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/transactions.html#managed-transaction-auto-callback-) model unless you have a really good reason not to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the `create` method.

To resolve the issue I had to create a new row using:

```js
var newKycDocument = await KYCDocument.create({
    kyc_id: checkUserKyc.dataValues.kyc_id,
    user_id: checkUserKyc.dataValues.user_id,
    document_name: doc.document_name,
    front_image: frontImgName,
    back_image: backImgName
}, {transaction})
```

I was missing the `.create` method.